# AS2 TweenLite: tween to frame

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, gsap

I have the following setup loaded:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([FramePlugin]);
OverwriteManager.init(OverwriteManager.AUTO);
```

and am using the following code to tween an mc to frame 20.

```
    TweenLite.to(circle, 1, {frame:20, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
```

Problem is nothing happens, circle is a variable containing my mc and traces fine.

Output of

```
trace(circle); = _level0.circle
```

Can anyone see why this isn't working? The MC contains a shapetween.

Edit:

Ok so I have tested it in a new fla with the same MC and it isn't the MC that is the problem it has to do with some other part of my code preventing it.

Here is my entire code... can anyone see anything that would stop the tween to frame working? If I remove `for (MovieClip in txts) {
    txts[MovieClip]._alpha = 0;
}` and put the tween above it it works, but as soon as it is inside a rollover again it doesn't.

Entire code:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([ColorTransformPlugin, FramePlugin]);
OverwriteManager.init(OverwriteManager.AUTO);
var angle:Number = 0;
var originX:Number = Stage.width/2;
var originY:Number = Stage.height/2;
var radiusX:Number = 320.5;
var radiusY:Number = 247.5;
var steps:Number = 360;
var speed:Number = 0.4/steps;
var circle:MovieClip = this.circle;
var circleTxt:MovieClip = this.circle.titleTxt;
var squareHeight:Number = 340.2;
var buttons:Array = new Array(this.faith, this.social, this.ability, this.age, this.orientation, this.ethnicity, this.sex);
var txts:Array = new Array("faithTxt", "socialTxt", "abilityTxt", "ageTxt", "orientationTxt", "ethnicityTxt", "sexTxt");
var tweens:Array = new Array();
for (MovieClip in txts) {
    txts[MovieClip]._alpha = 0;
}
for (i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onRollOver = function() {
        var current:MovieClip = this;
        circle.onEnterFrame = function() {
            if (this._currentframe == 20) {
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
                delete circleTxt.onEnterFrame;
                current.txt._alpha = 100;
            }
        };
        noScale(circleTxt);
        txtName = current._name+"Txt";
        current.txt = this._parent.attachMovie(txtName, txtName, this._parent.getNextHighestDepth());
        current.txt._alpha = 0;
        circle.txtHeight = circle.active.txt._height/2+40;
        var oppX:Number = Stage.width-this._x;
        var oppY:Number = Stage.height-this._y;
        if (oppX-227.8<=20) {
            var difference:Number = Math.abs(20-(oppX-227.8));
            oppX += difference;
        } else if (oppX+227.8>=Stage.width-20) {
            var difference:Number = Math.abs(780-(oppX+227.8));
            oppX -= difference;
        }
        if (oppY-172.1<=20) {
            var difference:Number = Math.abs(20-(oppY-172.1));
            oppY += difference;
        } else if (oppY+172.1>=580) {
            var difference:Number = Math.abs(580-(oppY+172.1));
            oppY -= difference;
        }
        circle.active.txt._x = oppX;
        circle.active.txt._y = oppY;
        TweenLite.to(circle,1,{frame:20});
        TweenLite.to(circle,0.5,{_height:circle.txtHeight});
        TweenLite.to(circle,1,{_x:oppX, _y:oppY, ease:Quint.easeInOut});
        TweenLite.to(circleTxt,1,{_alpha:0});
        TweenLite.to(this,0.5,{colorTransform:{tint:0x99ff00, tintAmount:0.5}});
        for (MovieClip in buttons) {
            delete buttons[MovieClip].onEnterFrame;
            if (buttons[MovieClip] != this) {
                TweenLite.to(buttons[MovieClip],0.5,{colorTransform:{tint:0xffffff, tintAmount:0.9}});
                TweenLite.to(buttons[MovieClip]._line,0.5,{colorTransform:{tint:0xffffff, tintAmount:0.9}});
            }
        }
    };
    buttons[i].onRollOut = function() {
        removeMovieClip(this.txt);
        circle.onEnterFrame = function() {
            if (this._currentframe == 1) {
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
                delete circleTxt.onEnterFrame;
            }
        };
        noScale(circleTxt);
        TweenLite.to(circle,0.2,{_height:173});
        TweenLite.to(circle,0.5,{_x:Stage.width/2, _y:Stage.height/2});
        TweenLite.to(circleTxt,1,{_alpha:100});
        for (MovieClip in buttons) {
            buttons[MovieClip].onEnterFrame = function() {
                moveButtons(this);
                controlButtons(this);
            };
            TweenLite.to(buttons[MovieClip],0.5,{colorTransform:{tint:null, tintAmount:0}});
            TweenLite.to(buttons[MovieClip]._line,0.5,{colorTransform:{tint:null, tintAmount:0}});
        }
    };
    buttons[i].onEnterFrame = function() {
        moveButtons(this);
        controlButtons(this);
    };
    buttons[i]._order = (360/buttons.length)*1000+(i+1);
    buttons[i]._linedepth = buttons[i].getDepth()-1000;
}
function noScale(mc) {
    mc.onEnterFrame = function() {
        this._yscale = 10000/this._parent._yscale;
    };
}
function moveButtons(e) {
    var lineName:String = new String(e._name+"line");
    var lineMC:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip(lineName, e._linedepth);
    with (lineMC) {
        beginFill();
        lineStyle(2,0x000000,100);
        moveTo(e._x,e._y);
        lineTo(Stage.width/2,Stage.height/2);
        endFill();
    }
    e.rotation = Math.atan2(e._y-Stage.height/2, e._x-Stage.width/2);
    e._line.dist = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(e._x-Stage.width/2) ^ 2+Math.abs(e._y-Stage.height/2) ^ 2);
    e._line = lineMC;
    e._anglePhase = (angle+e._order)/Math.PI*2.8;
    e._x = originX+Math.sin(e._anglePhase)*radiusX;
    e._y = originY+Math.cos(e._anglePhase)*radiusY;

}
function controlButtons(e) {
    angle += speed;
    if (angle>=360) {
        angle -= 360;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh Solved, for some reason it doesn't like `for (MovieClip in Array){}` anywhere in your code, so if I substitute that for `for (a in Array){}` it seems to work. Odd.